# migrate Spring app from XML to annotations

Tags: java, spring

I've inherited a Spring 3 app that uses XML files to define and wire together the beans. I know that since Spring 2 these can mostly be replaced with annotations. I would like Spring to:

- detect beans by scanning certain packages for classes with whatever annotation is used to indicate a Spring bean
- attempt to autowire-by-name and field in a bean that I have marked with the relevant annotation

What are steps I need to take to make this happen?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The manual has all the info you need: http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.0.M1/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-annotation-config

The TL;DR version is that you need to add `<context:annotation-config/>` to your spring config and then annotate your beans with `@Component` and in your setter of properties annotate with `@Autowired`

Comment: Just complementing CarlosZ's answer. If you're creating a new Component and you want to autowire some bean you don't have to create getters and setters, just add the @Autowired annotation to the property declaration and you're good to go.

Comment: Correct @Lucas, you can do setter injection, property injection (no setter needed) or constructor injection (my personal favorite as I'm of the opinion an object should be completely inited when the constructor is called, dependencies included).

Comment: new link: https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/core.html#beans-annotation-config

Answer (score 3):

> I shall give you a xml configuration with it anotation based config equivalent respectively, so that you will easily see how to change your bean from xml to java and vice-versa

```
    `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

        <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
               xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
               xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
               xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
               xsi:schemaLocation="
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans    
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.0.xsd
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.0.xsd">

            <context:component-scan base-package="com.mycompany.backendhibernatejpa.controller" />
            <mvc:annotation-driven />
            <bean id="iAbonneDao" class="com.mycompany.backendhibernatejpa.daoImpl.AbonneDaoImpl"/> 
            <bean id="iAbonneService" class="com.mycompany.backendhibernatejpa.serviceImpl.AbonneServiceImpl"/>

            <!-- couche de persistance JPA -->
            <bean id="entityManagerFactory"
                  class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
                <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
                <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
                    <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">            
                        <property name="databasePlatform" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect" />
                        <property name="generateDdl" value="true" />
                        <property name="showSql" value="true" />
                    </bean>
                </property>
                <property name="loadTimeWeaver">
                    <bean
                        class="org.springframework.instrument.classloading.InstrumentationLoadTimeWeaver" />
                </property>
            </bean>

            <bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">   
                <property name="locations" value="classpath:bd.properties"/>
            </bean>

            <!-- la source de donnéees DBCP -->
            <bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close" >
                <property name="driverClassName" value="${bd.driver}" />
                <property name="url" value="${bd.url}" />
                <property name="username" value="${bd.username}" />
                <property name="password" value="${bd.password}" />
            </bean>

            <!-- le gestionnaire de transactions -->

            <bean id="txManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
                <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
            </bean>


            <!-- traduction des exceptions -->
            <bean class="org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor" />

            <!-- annotations de persistance -->
            <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor" />


        </beans>`
```

> this file is named springrest-sevlet. actually you can give the name
>   you want followed by "-servlet" and mention that name in the file
>   web.xml

```
    ` <web-app> 
             <display-name>Gescable</display-name> 
             <servlet> 
                 <servlet-name>springrest</servlet-name> 
                 <servlet-class> org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet </servlet-class> 
                 <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup> 
             </servlet> 
             <servlet-mapping> 
                 <servlet-name>springrest</servlet-name> 
                 <url-pattern>/</url-pattern> 
             </servlet-mapping> 
         </web-app>`
```

> the two files should be place in the folder "WEB-INF". 
>               Now the equivalent with anotation based config

```
    `/*
         * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
         * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
         * and open the template in the editor.
         */
        package com.mycompany.backendhibernatejpaannotation.configuration;

        import com.mycompany.backendhibernatejpaannotation.daoImpl.AbonneDaoImpl;
        import com.mycompany.backendhibernatejpaannotation.daoInterface.IAbonneDao;
        import com.mycompany.backendhibernatejpaannotation.serviceImpl.AbonneServiceImpl;
        import com.mycompany.backendhibernatejpaannotation.serviceInterface.IAbonneService;
        import javax.sql.DataSource;
        import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
        import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
        import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
        import org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor;
        import org.springframework.instrument.classloading.InstrumentationLoadTimeWeaver;
        import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource;
        import org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager;
        import org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean;
        import org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor;
        import org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter;
        import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;

        /**
         *
         * @author vivien saa
         */
        @Configuration
        @EnableWebMvc
        @ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.mycompany.backendhibernatejpaannotation")
        public class RestConfiguration {

            @Bean
            public IAbonneDao iAbonneDao() {
                return new AbonneDaoImpl();
            }

            @Bean
            public IAbonneService iAbonneService() {
                return new AbonneServiceImpl();
            }

        //    @Bean
        //    public PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer placeholderConfigurer() {
        //        PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer placeholderConfigurer = new PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer();
        //        placeholderConfigurer.setLocations("classpath:bd.properties");
        //        return placeholderConfigurer;
        //    }

            @Bean
            public DataSource dataSource() {
                DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
                dataSource.setDriverClassName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
                dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/gescable");
                dataSource.setUsername("root");
                dataSource.setPassword("root");
                return dataSource;
            }

            @Bean
            public HibernateJpaVendorAdapter jpaVendorAdapter() {
                HibernateJpaVendorAdapter jpaVendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
                jpaVendorAdapter.setDatabasePlatform("org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect");
                jpaVendorAdapter.setGenerateDdl(true);
                jpaVendorAdapter.setShowSql(true);
                return jpaVendorAdapter;
            }

            @Bean
            public InstrumentationLoadTimeWeaver loadTimeWeaver() {
                InstrumentationLoadTimeWeaver loadTimeWeaver = new InstrumentationLoadTimeWeaver();
                return loadTimeWeaver;
            }

            @Bean
            public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory() {
                LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
                entityManagerFactory.setDataSource(dataSource());
                entityManagerFactory.setJpaVendorAdapter(jpaVendorAdapter());
                entityManagerFactory.setLoadTimeWeaver(loadTimeWeaver());
                return entityManagerFactory;
            }

            @Bean
            public JpaTransactionManager jpaTransactionManager() {
                JpaTransactionManager jpaTransactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
                jpaTransactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(entityManagerFactory().getObject());
                return jpaTransactionManager;
            }

            @Bean
            public PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostPro`enter code here`cessor persistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor() {
                return new PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor();
            }

            @Bean
            public PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor persistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor() {
                return new PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor();
            }

        }`
```

> this file must be accompanied by this one

```
`              
        package com.mycompany.backendhibernatejpaannotation.configuration;

        import org.springframework.web.servlet.support.AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer;

        /**
         *
         * @author vivien saa
         */
        public class Initializer extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {

            @Override
            protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
                return new Class[]{RestConfiguration.class};
            }

            @Override
            protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
                return null;
            }

            @Override
            protected String[] getServletMappings() {
                return new String[]{"/"};
            }

        }
        `
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the first thing to do is to go slow.  Just pick one service at a time and migrate it as you have cause to touch it.  Mucking with a ton of spring config is a sure way screw yourself in production with a dependency you only need once in a while.