# How can I migrate xml-based spring app to annotation-based automatically?

Tags: java, xml, spring, spring-boot, migration

I have to migrate an xml-based Spring application to annotation-based one. I just started to migrate the beans.
Not a hard task. If I see bean like that one:

```
<bean id="first-big-service-bean"
          class="com.place.place.FirstBigService.java">
        <property name="dao1" ref="dao1-name"></property>
        <property name="dao2" ref="dao2-name"></property>
        <property name="dao3" ref="dao3-name"></property>
        <property name="transformer1" ref="transformer1-name"></property>
        ...
        <property name="serviceX" ref="serviceX-name"></property>
 </bean>
```

1. I just put `@Repository` annotation above the daos class, and
   `@Service` annotation above services, transformers etc, etc.
2. After that, I put `@Autowired` annotation where I find these beans as a
   property.
3. After that I just remove all xml configured beans and
   aliases from xml files.

Easy, right?

The only problem with that is there are thousands of beans and 30-40 application context xml file. One is for the application and the others for tests.

As I see, it will be weeks...

I'm just wondering, are there any solution to do that automatically? If no, how can I do that on faster way?

I'm using IntelliJ and I use "Find in Files (Ctrls+Shift+F)" tool but there are a lot of cases where the beans aren't same than other. For example, the bean names are different or there is one or more additional whitespace character. So, this tool can't save time effectively.

Other problem: When I search where is used the bean, I get hundreds of places. So, I have to put the `@Autowired` annotation one by one. The first problem with that, my head will explode but the bigger problem is that, if I miss one or two, it will be hard to find the remaining properties.
Besides, the most of beans is prototype scoped. That means if I miss `@Autowired` annotation I will face errors when the property is injected and not at the creation of context, right? (Maybe I'm wrong)
What do you think? Can I miss this robot work?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5476125/migrate-spring-app-from-xml-to-annotations

Comment: Here is a [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5476125/migrate-spring-app-from-xml-to-annotations) to the stack overflow answer

Comment: Here is [documentation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5476125/migrate-spring-app-from-xml-to-annotations) you can follow

Comment: Thank you for your comment but I know and use this. The question is, I need taking the annotations and removing beans from xml files manually. Or, are there any forgotten technic which do this automatically?

Comment: OR if not automatically but faster way.